# How to associate two foreign key to a post on create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models as below and would like to associate two foreign key to a post on create (user_id (from User model) and review_id (from Review model) to Goal model. I manage to associate the user_id using 'current_user' to goals on create by using the solution given in the link below but not sure on how to go about getting this done as well for review_id.

Thanks.

[Devise how to associate current user to post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009295/devise-how-to-associate-current-user-to-post)

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base       
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :periods, :through => :reviews
  has_many :goals
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base       
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :period
  has_many :goals
end

class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base       
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :review
end
```

My goals_controller.rb

```
def create
  @goal = current_user.goals.build(params[:goal])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @goal.save
      format.html { redirect_to @goal, notice: 'Goal was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @goal, status: :created, location: @goal }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @goal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Cheers,
Azren

Comment: You've posted your `User` model twice.

Comment: Check again. There are still 2 `class User` statements. Although you've fixed their content.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand what the goal is. One general way I usually use is to model the relationships to something you are familiar with or you can easily find good examples. For example, think about your use case as user-question-answer models. Same as your use case, user has many questions and many answers. question has many answers and belongs to user, and answer belongs to user and question.

So things become easy, right? Let's see how stackoverflow implements this. You can check the html code of a comment box, and the form action is something like (/questions/10186415/answer/submit). Here 10186415 is the question id, it's passed to the server side, so when an answer is created, this question id can be used and related.

Back to your case, the goal form should know what review it's for. The review id could be a hidden field, or part of the submit url.

Comment: I've added '@review = Review.where("user_id = current_user")' into the controller 'create' and in my goal form '<%= f.hidden_field :review_id, :value => @review %>'. It saved successfully but without the review_id. Any idea?