# How to associate a Devise User with another existing model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new to Ruby on Rails and have setup Devise for authentication. I have an existing model that I created prior to adding Devise. That model is called Article. I believe I have done everything I need to do in order to use the `association=(associate)` method that ["assigns an associated object to this object. Behind the scenes, this means extracting the primary key from the associate object and setting this object’s foreign key to the same value"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) which is exactly what I need to do.

Here is Devise's User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    has_one :article
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Here is my Article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

Here is my migration:

```
class AddUserRefToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      add_reference :articles, :user, index: true
    end
end
```

Here is my create method from my `articles_controller.rb`:

```
def create
@article.user = current_user

@article = Article.new(post_params)

        if @article.save
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'new'
        end
end
```

And here is what happens when my controller runs:

```
NoMethodError in ArticlesController#create
undefined method `user=' for nil:NilClass
```

The highlighted code is `@article.user = current_user`. I was at least glad to know that I wrote that line of code similar to the popular answer in the [Devise how to associate current user to post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009295/devise-how-to-associate-current-user-to-post) question that I saw on here before posting this one.

I know I'm making a rookie mistake. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new `User` instance needs to be assigned to `@article` **before** you can access any of the instance's attributes/associations. Try the following:

```
@article = Article.new(post_params) # Assign first
@article.user = current_user        # Then access attributes/associations
```

The code posted in the question yields a `nil:NilClass`exception because the `user` association is being invoked on `@article`, which is `nil` because *nothing has yet been assigned to it*.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. But, can you explain what exactly is going on with `@article = Article.new(post_params)`? I don't see how it has anything to do with assigning a `User` instance to anything.

Comment: Unless you assign something to the instance variable `@article`, it will be `nil`. Assigning it `Article.new` means that `@article` is now a new instance of `Article` – it is no longer `nil`. Instances of `Article` have an association to a `User` setter, which is what you assign `current_user` to.

Comment: Michael - basically the reason you need to put article.user = current_user is that when the new record is created in the db the field "user" in your "articles" table will be populated with the id of the current_user. This is how the relationship between a user and an article is made. Devise gives you the 'current_user' object, other than that devise doesn't get involved in the process. The relationship is an "Active Record Association", give this a read for more info http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: You can simplify this with a single line of code: `@article = current_user.build_article(post_params)`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-belongs-to-build-association-attributes