# How to add products to the Devise user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, associations, ruby-on-rails-6

I am beginner in Ruby on Rails and am trying to create a Shopper application in rails. There are 3 models : Batch, Product, User(Devise). Each batch has many products and each user has many products. I have created an association(has_many) between User and Product. How to add the specific product(Each product has a link to the products path) to the current user logged in if I click the link Buy.

My User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

My Product model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :batch
  belongs_to :user
  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  root to: 'batches#index'
  resources "batches", only: %i[index show]
  resources "products"
end
```

Schema file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_06_16_134907) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "batches", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "code"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "batch_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["batch_id"], name: "index_products_on_batch_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_products_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "products", "batches"
end
```

Products controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @products = Product.order(:name)
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def create
    @product = current_user.products.build(params[:product])
    if @product.save
      puts 'yes'
    else
      puts 'no'
    end
  end

  private
  def prod_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :user_id)
  end
end
```

Suggest me to specify the redirect_to links if the product is added to the user. I am printing a message. Clearly it didn't print it. 
I also referred this: [How to associate a Devise User with another existing model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680456/how-to-associate-a-devise-user-with-another-existing-model)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting that after the product is saved, it should be redirected to some other path? And the path being the products that the currently user has bought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused about the actual problem you are having, but if your question is about links to your newly created Product... Your routes file defines products as:

```
resources 'products'
```

This will create a set of routes that have the base form:

```
<root>/product/:id
```

So, the URI namespace for your products is not currently scoped by user, and all you need is a product ID. So, if you have want to include a link to a user's set of products, you could do something like:

```
<% current_user.products.each do |product|%>
  <%= link_to product.name, product_path(product.id) %>
<% end %>
```

If you really want the paths to products to be scoped by each user, you can do that too. The routes file allows you to nest resources inside another like this:

```
resource :users do
  resources :products
end
```

That will generate routes of the form:

```
<root>/users/:user_id/products/:id
```

I suggest checking out the Rails Guide page on routes ( https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to get an idea of the various things you can do to set up routes the way you want them.