# Pg:Error column does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise

I am trying to make it so a user has_many goals, and then only let a user see their own goals. 
My welcome controller where the code is failing:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if user_signed_in?
      @goals = current_user.goals.all
    else
      @goals = Hash.new
    end
  end
end
```

User.rb is like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :goals
end
```

And my Goal.rb:

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The error I am getting is:

```
PG::Error: ERROR: column goals.user_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "goals".* FROM "goals" WHERE "goals"."user_id" = $1 ^ : SELECT "goals".* FROM "goals" WHERE "goals"."user_id" = $1
```

(I get this error while logged in, after having created a new goal)

I tried adding "foreign_key :user_id" to my User model but then I get the following error:

```
/Users/Thomas/newyears/app/models/user.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' has_many :goals, foreign_key :user_id ^
```

In my routes file on line 3, which looks like this:

```
Goalsy::Application.routes.draw do
  get "mycalendar/index"
  devise_for :users
  devise_for :goals
  resources :goals

  get "welcome/index"
  resources :posts

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Comment: In your Goals Migration did you add the column user_id ? If yes, after creating your migration did you migrate your schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, the user_id column is missing in the goals table.

Just run the command in your console to create the migration

```
rails generate migration AddUserRefToGoals user:references
```

It will generate the migration file.

```
class AddUserRefToGoals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :goals, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

Then do the `rake db:migrate`

Hope, it will fix your problem.

Comment: That fixed the error (thank you!), but my goals do not display properly. If I do "Goal.all" I see all goals, but "current_user.goals.all" returns nothing. I am guessing current_user is not working for some reason.

Comment: I believe, when you are saving a goal, the current_user.id is not saving in the user_id column of goals. So it returns a blank array [].

Comment: Thank you for your help! I fixed the current_user =! user problem with the help of this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009295/devise-how-to-associate-current-user-to-post