# Associate devise user with post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, devise

I am using devise and now I am trying to associate users to articles.

I read few posts on stackoverflow but I have hard time understanding how it will work in my application. I tried to understand [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009295/devise-how-to-associate-current-user-to-post) but it seems like black magic...

Database: MongoDB (mongoid gem)

Here is what I have:

article_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.update(article_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: 'Article was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :content)
    end
end
```

article.rb

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user

  field :title, type: String
  field :content, type: String
  field :user, type: String

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

user.rb

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :articles
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  # ... devise configurations
end
```

I have low understanding of how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first in the article model, you have to remove this line

```
field :user, type: String
```

this is wrong as it will conflict with the method generated by Mongoid to get the user relation.

secondly, you have to correctly construct the article object...
this can be done by any of the following code

```
# METHOD 1
@article = Article.create!(
  title: article_params[:article][:title],
  content: article_params[:article][:content],
  user: current_user
  # or user_id: current_user.id
)

# METHOD 2
@article = current_user.articles.create!(article_params)

# METHOD 3
# this is mentioned in other answer as well ( but added also here for completeness )
@article = Article.new(article_params)
@article.user = current_user
@article.save!
```

and to elaborate on how this is working (on the question you referred to) I'll explain how each method works...

#### Method 1

In this approach, you are creating an object and setting all of it's attributes manually... this means that you are overriding the `:user` or `:user_id` with the correct values they expect to serialize the object correctly to the DB (whether it's mongoDB or Postgres or whatever)

#### Method 2

In this approach, you are grabbing the user model itself and creating the article using the relation helper methods... which will automatically figure the `user_id` attribute for the article and set it correctly with the rest of the relations... ( since user has many articles... any `user.articles.create!` will grab the relation `user_id`

#### Method 3

In this approach, you create a ruby object ( not a database record... yet) using the `@article = Article.new(article_params)` with a subset of the required attributes... and you don't persist that the DB (yet)...
then you set the `article <-> user` relation manually yourself...
and lastly you persist that record to the DB using the `.save` or `.save!`

Comment: I used Method 2 - thanks for explaining it. Its easier then I thought it actually is.
Now, how would I see if this user is actually assigned to this article? I used `<%= @article.user %>` and it gives me this: `#<User:0x007fdcd340d8c0>`

Comment: which is correct i think... to further investigate... you can show `@article.user.id` or `@article.user.email` or whatever you want...
`@article.user` returns the whole user object ( which you can use to do whatever you want to do with )... if you are familiar with the concept of ORMs then you should be fine

Comment: Yes, ture - my brain is switched off today. So solution to this in my case will be `<%= @article.user.username %>` which will look for article/user/username. Thanks a lot @mad_raz

Answer (score 1):

In your articles_controller, same thing as in linked answer:

`@article.user = current_user`